# Need MySQL query to retrieve a second value based on the most frequently occuring row

Tags: mysql, sum

The following query detects the most occurrences of `diallednumber`:

```
SELECT COUNT( * ) AS  `Rows` , diallednumber
FROM logData
GROUP BY diallednumber
ORDER BY  `Rows` DESC 
LIMIT 20
```

I have another column to show cost of `diallednumber`.

I am unable to to write a query to provide the most expensive `diallednumber` based on the number of times it has occurred.

Comment: and we should just be able to magically guess how you're storing call cost data? `sum(cost_of_dialing)`?

Comment: @MarcB: what happened to your mind-reading skills — or the ability to read between the lines?  (You're right; the information is not given and we have to guess.)

Answer (score 2):

#### Number of calls per number

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS calls, dialledNumber
  FROM logData
 GROUP BY dialledNumber
```

#### Largest number of calls to a number

```
SELECT MAX(calls) AS maxCalls
  FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) AS calls, dialledNumber
          FROM logData
         GROUP BY dialledNumber
       ) AS c
```

#### Sum of cost of calls to number with largest number of calls

```
SELECT SUM(l.cost), l.dialledNumber
  FROM logData AS l
  JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS calls, dialledNumber
          FROM logData
         GROUP BY dialledNumber
       ) AS c
    ON l.dialledNumber = c.dialledNumber
  JOIN (SELECT MAX(calls) AS maxCalls
          FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) AS calls, dialledNumber
                  FROM logData
                 GROUP BY dialledNumber
               )
       ) AS m
    ON m.maxCalls = c.calls
```

If there are two numbers with the same maximum number of calls, both will be shown.  You can dink with a maximum of the sum of the costs if you want to get fancy.

The `m` subquery might be used without a join as a 'simple' number:

```
SELECT SUM(l.cost), l.dialledNumber
  FROM logData AS l
  JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS calls, dialledNumber
          FROM logData
         GROUP BY dialledNumber
       ) AS c
    ON l.dialledNumber = c.dialledNumber
   AND c.calls = (SELECT MAX(calls) AS maxCalls
                    FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) AS calls, dialledNumber
                            FROM logData
                           GROUP BY dialledNumber
                         )
                 ) AS m
```

A good optimizer will use the same query plan for both.

Comment: That was a quick response, thank you. I'll play with this and just check I'm getting what I need and post back. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

And largest cost:

```
SELECT diallednumber
     , COUNT(diallednumber)
     , SUM(cost) 
  FROM logdata 
 GROUP 
    BY diallednumber 
 ORDER 
    BY SUM(cost) DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Have found the queries in all perfect for what I needed. Thank you.